# Yii2 - Ajax CSRF Token: Unexpected token "-"

Tags: ajax, yii2

In yii advanced template, I am trying to send something via ajax without disable csrf validation.

However, _csrf-frontend caused an error called " Unexpected token - "

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "'.Url::to(["testctrl/testact"]).'",
  data: {prod_id:id,_csrf-frontend:'.Yii::$app->request->csrfToken.'}
});
```

What should I use instead?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this format.

```
'_csrf-frontend':'".Yii::$app->request->csrfToken."',
```

**I think this will work for you**